# How to modify deep vuex data with v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to modify a vuex store, but using v-model on a key deep inside the object. Obviously when modifying data it must be done using mutations. But i'm struggling to figure out how to do this with a deep value.

Here's a fiddle, which should generate a vuex error (the error isn't generated in the fiddle for some reason):

`[vuex] Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers`

https://jsfiddle.net/antony_publica/L27pcksn/70/

How can I setup a computed value for an object thats inside an object returned from a state without having to copy that entire dataset to another variable and track all the changes manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to use a computed property for this. Don't use `v-model`, instead bind to `:value` and register your own event listener.

https://jsfiddle.net/jamesbrndwgn/L27pcksn/88/

You may also want to read about [normalizing state shape](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape). It will make working with Objects much simpler and avoid deep nesting.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have made my fiddle a very simple version of what i'm doing. I'm using a drag and drop component which modifies the original data with v-model or a prop. I think I can get it to work with some work arounds. The advice you gave is solid though so i've accepted your answer