# Vuex Form Handling with an Array of Objects / Objects

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I've been trying to implement some functionality to my Vue app using Vuex. I've noticed that handling forms with Vuex can be pretty rough... Pretty much my whole app is based around a single object that needs to be tracked in the store (at least, that's my belief. Maybe there is a better alternative?) That object looks something like this:

```
person: {
  basicInformation: {
    first: '',
    last: '',
    email: '',
    phone: '',
    street: '',
    city: '',
    position: '',
    website: '',
  },
  about: '',
  knowledge: '',
  experience: [
    {
      company: '',
      position: '',
      description: '',
      website: '',
      date: [],
    },
  ],
}
```

The values should be entered by the user with an inputform. That's easy without Vuex. Then you could simply do something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Mertakus/du10928s/).

With Vuex, it'll look something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Mertakus/91rzth2m/9/). Where a getter and setter is created for the piece of state. That works fine for one single 'message' item. I can't get that to work with a large object that also contains nested objects and arrays though. How would I pass the index in the actions/mutations and how would that be passed in the getter and setter? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53843292/how-to-modify-deep-vuex-data-with-v-model?rq=1) post that correlates most to my problem. But I still cannot get it to work. Could someone help me out here and point me in the right direction? If you need more information, feel free to ask.

Comment: Could you explain why do you need/want to store your large `person` object in Vuex ? Is this object used/required by several components which are not direct children of the component where the form is ? I think you are over-complicating the solution.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't track the object in your Form component locally with `v-model` and then commit it to the state once when the form is submitted?

Comment: I had no problem with feeding the store containing a very complex object. I don't understand in your question, why are single actions not good for your usecase? I mean the user does not update everything at once, but field by field? And if you want to update your object at once when the user posted whole form or something than one commit with everything will do the trick? Please provide more info on the interface code.